# How find the $x+y+z$ rang if $\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}+\sqrt{z^2+z}=2$

Tags: inequality

let $x,y,z\ge 0$,and such
$$\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}+\sqrt{z^2+z}=2$$

Assmue that $x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,xyz$ range of is $A,B,C$ respectively

Find the $A\bigcap B\bigcap C$

and I think we can find the $A,B,C$.

my idea:
Use AM-GM inequality, we have
$$x^2+x\ge 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}\Longrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+x}\ge \sqrt{2}x^{\frac{3}{4}}$$
so
we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2+x}\ge \sqrt{2}\sum_{cyc}x^{\frac{3}{4}}\ge 3\sqrt{2}(xyz)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
so
$$\Longrightarrow xyz\le\dfrac{1}{27}$$
so
$$C=\{x|0\le x\le\dfrac{1}{27}\}$$
But for $A,B$ it seems not easy.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x+y+z = p$.  By Minkowski's inequality,
$$2 = \sum_{cyc} \sqrt{x^2+x} \ge \sqrt{p^2+\left(\sum_{cyc} \sqrt x \right)^2} \ge \sqrt{p^2+p} \implies p \le \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}2$$

Equality is achieved when any two among $x, y, z$ are zero, so this is the maximum of the range $A$.

OTOH, considering the concave function $t \mapsto \sqrt {t^2+t}$, Jensen's inequality gives
$$2 = \sum_{cyc} \sqrt{x^2+x} \le 3\sqrt{p^2/9+ p/3} \implies p \ge 1$$
Equality is achieved when $x=y=z=\frac13$.

The above two bounds give $A = \left[1, \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}2 \right]$.

---

For $B$, consider $x^2+y^2+z^2=q$.  Clearly $3q \ge p^2\ge 1$, and $q = \frac13$ is achieved when $x=y=z=\frac13$, so $q \ge \frac13$ gives the minimum.

We also know $q \le p^2 \le \frac{9-\sqrt{17}}2$, and this is achieved when any two among $x, y, z$ are zero.  So $B = \left[\frac13, \frac{9-\sqrt{17}}2 \right]$.

Of course $A \cap C = \phi$, so we needed only to show $p\ge  1$ and $xyz \le \frac1{27}$if the aim is to find $A \cap B \cap C$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you +1